# Retrieve DSA key passphrase

Tags: ssh, centos, dsa, passphrase

I use dsa key with passphrase to login via ssh into CentOS 6 remote server. Unfortunately I forgot the passphrase.

Is there a way to reset or retrieve passsphrase?

I still do have access to root of remote server through webmin.

Answer (score 0):

no, the keyfile itself does not hold any data that would aid you in breaking/recovering (quite the same) the encryption. if you did not back up the information otherwise, you cannot recover it.

you however simply install a new key.